# What causes "irrefutable pattern failed for pattern" and what does it mean?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, runtime-error

What does

> irrefutable pattern failed for pattern

mean?
What cases will cause this runtime error?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Well, I assume it means what it says - that a pattern doesn't match but there is no alternative. This example:

> But for the program:
>
> ```
> g x = let Just y = f x in h y
> ```
>
> GHC reports:
>
> ```
> Main: M1.hs:9:11-22:
>     Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern Data.Maybe.Just y
> ```
>
> Indicating the source of the failure.

Comes from http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Debugging

The point of the example is that if `f x` returns `Nothing` then there is no way GHC can assign a value to `y`.

Answer (score 28):

Consider this example:

```
foo ~(Just x) = "hello"
main = putStrLn $ foo Nothing
```

This uses an irrefutable pattern (the `~` part). Irrefutable patterns always "match", so this prints `hello`.

```
foo ~(Just x) = x
main = putStrLn $ foo Nothing
```

Now, the pattern still matched, but when we tried to use `x` when it wasn't actually there there we got an irrefutable pattern match error:

```
Irr.hs: /tmp/Irr.hs:2:1-17: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern (Data.Maybe.Just x)
```

This is subtly distinct from the error you get when there's no matching pattern:

```
foo (Just x) = x
main = putStrLn $ foo Nothing
```

This outputs

```
Irr.hs: /tmp/Irr.hs:2:1-16: Non-exhaustive patterns in function foo
```

---

Of course, this is a somewhat contrived example. The more likely explanation is that it came from a pattern in a `let` binding, [as chrisdb suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711870/what-are-the-cases-that-will-cause-irrefutable-pattern-failed-for-pattern/6711945#6711945).

Comment: I think that might be mistaken `~xyz` (IMO it's called *lazy pattern*) is one example of an irrefutable pattern but not the only one - I just remark because I saw people calling `~` **the** irrefutable pattern

Answer (score 9):

To add what others have said, you could technically get it if you're disconnecting a list that's smaller than what you're intending. For example (in GHCi):

```
Prelude> let l = [1,2,3]
Prelude> let (x:x1:xs) = l
Prelude> x
1
```

Works fine, but if you did:

```
Prelude> let l2 = [1]
Prelude> let (x:x1:xs) = l2
Prelude> x
*** Exception: <interactive>:294:5-18: Irrefutable pattern failed for pattern (x : x1 : xs)
```

Comment: *deconstructing.