# How does the second parameter become a list of functions?

Tags: haskell, zipwith

I am playing a bit with `zipWith` and encounter following:

```
Prelude Control.Applicative> :t zipWith id
zipWith id :: [b -> c] -> [b] -> [c]
```

Why does the compiler expect for the next argument a list of functions?

I tried to analyze, but could not conclude, why the next argument must be a list of functions.

How did the signature is getting apply, when I pass `id` to `zipWith`?

Comment: Worth noting that this is more commonly written `zipWith ($)`. Which works exactly the same way; the `$` operator is simply a type-narrowed version of `id`.

Comment: If you've "tried to analyze", you should include the details of your attempted analysis, or potential answerers may be simply re-explaining that which you do understand, and completely missing that which you don't.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The type of `zipWith` is:

```
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

And the type of `id` is:

```
id :: d -> d
```

So if we now want to derive the type of `zipWith id`, we push the type of `id :: d -> d` into the type of the first argument of `zipWith`:

```
  d -> d
~ a -> (b -> c)
```

So that means that: `a ~ d` and `a ~ b -> c`. So that means that the type of `zipWith id` is now:

```
   zipWith id :: [a] -> [b] -> [c]
-> zipWith id :: [b -> c] -> [b] -> [c]
```

How does this work: the first list has to contain a list of functions `f :: b -> c`, and the second list, a list of elements `x :: b`, and it thus calculates a list of elements `f x :: c`.

For example:

```
Prelude> zipWith id [(+1),(5/),(3*),(3-)] [1,4,2,5]
[2.0,1.25,6.0,-2.0]
```

since `1+1` is `2.0`, `5/4` is `1.25`, `3*2` is `6.0` and `3-5` is `-2.0`.

So `zipWith id` will take two elements `f` and `x`, and apply `id f x` on these, or more verbose `(id f) x`. Since `id f` is `f`, it will thus calculate `f x`.

We can thus conclude that `zipWith` is an *elementwise* mapping.

Comment: What does the `~` mean?

Comment: @zero_coding: it means [*type equality*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27667708/67579). So for instance `a ~ d` means that `a` and `d` are the same types. [further reading](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#Equality_constraints).

Comment: @zero_coding I have added an answer that can make you understand with out the `~`. Just though simple type inference logic. But, @Willem Van Onsem answer is really great.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you, Willem Van Onsem for the great answer.

> Let's understand `zipWith id` from the eyes of the type inference system of ghc.

first, consider the type of `zipWith`

```
Prelude> :info zipWith
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.List’
```

First argument of `zipWith` is a function which accepts a function which takes two arguments.

`(a -> b -> c)`  can also be re-written as `a -> (b -> c)`

now consider `zipWith id`. type of `id` is from `a -> a`

we have put `id` in a place where a two argument function must go.

So, type inference would make `(a -> b -> c)` look like `a -> (b -> c)` (notice `a -> (b -> c)` takes one arument a and gives `b -> c` i.e a single argument function.)

But, making `a -> (b -> c)` an identity function would be possible only if `a` is (b -> c).

When `a` is (b -> c) the function `a -> b -> c` becomes ((b -> c) -> (b -> c))

So, type inferencing system would infer `a` as `(b -> c)` and the resultant output would be `[a] -> [b] -> [c]` replacing `a` with `b -> c`.

> Replace `a` with (b -> c).
>
> Make (a -> b -> c) look like `id`. (a -> b -> c) can be made to look like `id` by the above replacement.
>
> ((b -> c) -> b -> c) which can also be written as ((b -> c) -> (b -> c)) which is `id :: x -> x` where `x` is (b -> c)

```
zipWith :: ((b -> c) -> b -> c) -> [b -> c] -> [b] -> [c]
```

So finally we get output as `[b -> c] -> [b] -> [c]`